# Code works in JSfiddle but not on local host

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsfiddle

I am trying to create a live rendering box where I can click and drag to scale. I found this example,

http://jsfiddle.net/d9BPz/546/

but when I run it locally, nothing appears. I figure it has to do with the CSS styling. I thought you're not allowed to give JS variables CSS styling.

```
.rectangle {
border: 1px solid #FF0000;
position: absolute;
}
```

I made sure to correctly add the javascript and css files in the index file.

Comment: I get an empty canvas in that fiddle.

Comment: Please check your browser console and post any error messages that you see there.

Comment: @ScottMarcus You have to click then drag. It's a canvas

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onmousemove' of null

Comment: Ok, I spent time on this finally realizing that this is not actually the HTML5 `canvas`!  Anyway, I don't know what to tell you. It looks good. I've modified the code to modernize it and streamline it here: http://jsfiddle.net/d9BPz/833/

Answer (score 1):

In your local machine, write the script in body after `<div id="canvas"></div>`

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#canvas {
    width:2000px;
    height:2000px;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
}
.rectangle {
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
    position: absolute;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="canvas"></div>
<script>
initDraw(document.getElementById('canvas'));



function initDraw(canvas) {
    function setMousePosition(e) {
        var ev = e || window.event; //Moz || IE
        if (ev.pageX) { //Moz
            mouse.x = ev.pageX + window.pageXOffset;
            mouse.y = ev.pageY + window.pageYOffset;
        } else if (ev.clientX) { //IE
            mouse.x = ev.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
            mouse.y = ev.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
        }
    };

    var mouse = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        startX: 0,
        startY: 0
    };
    var element = null;
    canvas.onmousemove = function (e) {
        setMousePosition(e);
        if (element !== null) {
            element.style.width = Math.abs(mouse.x - mouse.startX) + 'px';
            element.style.height = Math.abs(mouse.y - mouse.startY) + 'px';
            element.style.left = (mouse.x - mouse.startX < 0) ? mouse.x + 'px' : mouse.startX + 'px';
            element.style.top = (mouse.y - mouse.startY < 0) ? mouse.y + 'px' : mouse.startY + 'px';
        }
    }

    canvas.onclick = function (e) {
        if (element !== null) {
            element = null;
            canvas.style.cursor = "default";
            console.log("finsihed.");
        } else {
            console.log("begun.");
            mouse.startX = mouse.x;
            mouse.startY = mouse.y;
            element = document.createElement('div');
            element.className = 'rectangle'
            element.style.left = mouse.x + 'px';
            element.style.top = mouse.y + 'px';
            canvas.appendChild(element)
            canvas.style.cursor = "crosshair";
        }
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You are getting exception because it is trying to set onmouseover event before loading the canvas object.

Comment: For me your code works fine. But if there is a problem with the not build canvas-object you can use <body onload="myFunction()"> and function my_function() { initDraw(document.getElementById('canvas')); }. This should work definitly.

Comment: @Sascha That will work as well. I just mentioned one way. They are other ways like document.onload etc. Thanks.